# Oracle APEX Data load definition with default column value?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am using Oracle APEX 21.1

I am trying to create Data loading page with data load definition, which is required with APEX 21.1.
I have bulk upload on MD page, so I have PX_ID item which i want to set as default (fk column) for all new rows from bulk upload.

Comment: so did you find a solution or should i re-ask the question?